# Need IP for my Virtual Machine

Tags: centos, ip, virtual-machine

I want to `scp` to my virtual machine (CentOS 6) from my Windows 8 machine. I have installed VMPlayer and  installed CentOS 6 on my machine. I have enabled Bridged adapter setting, but I still can't see an IP address for the virtual machine.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are trying to learn what ip is assigned to the VM or if you are asking how to set up IP networking in the VM?

Comment: I have a static configuration on my Windows 8 machine and I have provided bridge adapter setting on my virtual box console.When I do ifconfig I do not see the ip.Only ethernet and loopback address ip could be seen.I am not able to ping the router gateway also.Please do let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: Your ethernet address should be the VMs IP. But it could be blocked by a firewall.

Comment: I need a different ip for my virtual machine and thus I have configured it to DHCP.My understanding was bridged adapter setting provides a new dynamic ip to the virtual box where as NAT setting is to have the the same ip as the ethernet address.Could you clarify if my understanding is correct

Answer (score 1):

Check in your VM what the IP address is by using `ifconfig`. If there is no such an address then maybe the bridging is not working. So check if the DHCP server got a request for the MAC address first. If not Windows 8 is blocking access and/or the Bridge is not properly working.

If your DHCP server gives out an IP for the MAC address, but `ifconfig` has no value then there is something wrong in CentOS not storing the IP handed out by the DHCP server.

If you have an IP address in the VM but cannot reach it from outside, then you  a problem with Windows 8 firewall not allowing reaching the VM.

Answer (score 1):

While being in bridged mode, you still need to assign an IP address to your VM. If you're not using DHCP for IP addressing, you need to create a network configuration. For CentOS 6 this can be done by altering (or creating) the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file.

It should look somewhat like this:

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=<MAC address should be here already>
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=<IPv4 address here>
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DNS1=<Primary DNS IP>
DNS2=<Secondary DNS IP>
TYPE=Ethernet
GATEWAY=<Gateway address> # Usually your router
USERCTL=no
# If you want to use IPv6 as well, also set the below fields
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=<IPv6 Address>/48 # Subnet may differ
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=<IPv6 Gateway>
IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES=<Additional IPv6 Address>/48 # Subnet may differ
```

By default, there should already be a file like this, but if you didn't specify a manual IP configuration during the CentOS installation, it will be set for DHCP networking. The most important values to change are `IPADDR`, `NETMASK`, `DNS1` and `DNS2`. Set these to the values that are right for your network, then restart the network service:

```
service network restart
```

Everything should come up just fine and you should be able to SCP into the machine. You can verify the IP configuration by running:

```
ifconfig eth0
```

If SCP'ing still doesn't work after setting a static IP, iptables is most likely blocking access. Either add a rule for your local machine to be allowed or disable iptables (`service iptables stop;chkconfig iptables off`). To allow your machine, edit the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` rule file and add:

```
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.10 -j ACCEPT
```

Where `192.168.1.10` should be the IP address of your host machine. Don't forget to reload the config by restarting iptables:

```
service iptables restart
```